# MySQL Update using a RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a query where I am trying to add rows to table x from table y where an id field in y is not in table x. I am trying to use a RIGHT JOIN to do this:

```
UPDATE table_x x

RIGHT JOIN
       table_y y
    ON y.id = x.id

SET 
y.id = x.id,
y.col1 = x.col1,
y.col2 = x.col2,
y.col3 = x.col3

WHERE y.id IS NULL
```

This works as a SELECT statement but for some reason the UPDATE isn't working. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: You cannot ADD rows with an UPDATE you need an INSERT.

Comment: Just Wondering `"y.id = x.id"` and updating id Column with right Join. What you are trying to Achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Insert rows in table x you probably want an INSERT statement instead of an UPDATE statement -

```
INSERT INTO table_x (id, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT y.id, y.col1, y.col2, y.col3
  FROM table_x x
 RIGHT JOIN table_y y ON y.id = x.id
 WHERE y.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Ankit's answer is correct except for the WHERE clause. You want to insert into table_x as table_x is missing data, not table_y as is implied in Ankit's SQL. Hence, you should have x.id instead of y.id in the WHERE:

```
WHERE x.id IS NULL
```

This will insert into table_x wherever there is data in table_y and not in table_x.

For clarity, the full syntax would therefore be:

```
INSERT INTO table_x (id, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT y.id, y.col1, y.col2, y.col3
  FROM table_x x
 RIGHT JOIN table_y y ON y.id = x.id
 WHERE x.id IS NULL
```